# i have a problem with running an app on android studio

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZKUQ.png)

I don't know where is the problem here

Answer (score 0):

1. in your build.gradle(Project) file
   use `mavenCentral()` instead of `jcenter()`

By doing so, maven now becomes the primary repository for all non-Google artifacts.

2. Clean and Rebuild your project

Comment: how to clean and rebuild project!

Comment: click on ```Build``` tab, you'll see ```clean``` and ```Rebuild```

Comment: Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details

Answer (score 0):

1. On Android Studio Click the **SDK Manager** Icon on the toolbar

[image]

2. On the dialog **SDK Tools** Tab - 2nd Tab

[image]

3. At the bottom of the dialogue window **Tick the Checkbox for Show Package Details**

4.Next **find Build 31.0.0 and uncheck it** to uninstall it

[image]

5.Press **Apply** and **OK** Buttons to exit the dialogue

6. Now Repeat Step 1-4 but this time **check/tick the checkbox to install another version** of Build Tools 31.0.0.0
7. Restart Android Studio and the problem should be resolved.

For the Merger problem, you need to open your Manifest file and add this line of code inside the `<activity><activity/>` tag

```
android:exported="true"
```

[image]

Comment: Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details

Comment: Hi Youssef, you need to add `android:exported="true"` inside the your `AndroidManifest.xml` file as shown above.